# Gspread is retrieving all strings from a Google Sheet named range even when some cells are numbers

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

When I use Gspread to open a Google Sheet and retrieve a named range, what is returned is a list of lists where every data point is a string. Here is a sample sheet:

[image: Google Sheet sample]

The cells a1:e5 are a named range called NamedRange1.

I can import NamedRange1 as follows:

```
wks = gc.open("Gspread_test").sheet1
data_range = wks.get("NamedRange1") # arrives as list of lists
```

What appears in Python, although the source is a mix of strings and numbers, is a list of lists that is all strings:

```
[['Able', 'Baker', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo'],
 ['Blue', 'New York', '3', '', '100'],
 ['Green', 'New Jersey', '4', '5', '100'],
 ['Red', 'New York', '', '6', '100'],
 ['Orange', 'New Jersey', '7', '', '100']]
```

How can I retrieve the data from Google Sheets so that numbers come in as numbers (and strings as strings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?hl=en), you can configure [valueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) on how values should be represented in the output.

[image]

Hence, If you want to read the range values as int, set `valueRenderOption` to `UNFORMATTED_VALUE`. (Default render option is `FORMATTED_VALUE`)

```
data_range = wks.get("NamedRange1", value_render_option='UNFORMATTED_VALUE')
```

**Additional Reference:** [Gspread get(range_name=None, **kwargs)](http://get(range_name=None,%20**kwargs))

Comment: I verified the configuration using the API explorer, just let me know if you encountered an issue when implementing it in your side so I could update the answer accordingly

Comment: This worked perfectly, at least for my use case.